# Streambuilder build getting triggered unnecessarily

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am using bloc pattern with inherited widget for state management.
The issue is i have used a streambuilder that listens and fetch session and saved that to get the first intial screen (login ,home , onboarding ,etc)
In any of the app areas keyboard is opened it triggers the stream builder build method and rebuilds all the widget and logic under it.
code :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
final UserStateBloc userStateBloc = UserStateBlocProvider.of(context);
final LoginViaOtpBloc loginViaOtpBloc = LoginViaOtpBlocProvider.of(context);
final AnalyticsBloc analyticsBloc = AnalyticsBlocProvider.of(context);
final UtilsBloc utilsBloc = UtilsBlocProvider.of(context);
routines(context);
return StreamBuilder<String>(
  stream: userStateBloc.currentUserState,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> appState) {
    if (!appState.hasData) {
      return const DefaultLoading(
        needsScaffold: true,
      );
    }
    if (match(appState.data, AppStates.onBoarding)) {
      analyticsBloc.logScreenChangeEvent(onBoardingSliderScreen);
      return routeAfterBuilding(context, onBoardingSliderScreen);
    } else if (match(appState.data, AppStates.checkPermission)) {
      analyticsBloc.logScreenChangeEvent(allocatePermissionRoute);
      return routeAfterBuilding(context, allocatePermissionRoute);
    } else if (match(appState.data, AppStates.logIn)) {
      analyticsBloc.logScreenChangeEvent(authVerificationRoute);
      userStateBloc.changeBtmNavbarState(0);
      loginViaOtpBloc.fetchDeviceInfo();
      if (loginViaOtpBloc.readPhoneNumber != "") {
        loginViaOtpBloc.changePhoneNumber("");
      }
      utilsBloc.agreedTermsAndCondtion(true);
      return routeAfterBuilding(context, authVerificationRoute);
    } else if (match(appState.data, AppStates.student) ||
        match(appState.data, AppStates.professional) ||
        match(appState.data, AppStates.other)) {
      analyticsBloc.setUserProfileType(appState.data.toString());
      return renderHome(context, appState.data!, null, true, true);
    } else {
      analyticsBloc.logError(AnalyticsConstants.profileType, defaultRoute,
          errorProps: {'profile_type': appState.data});
      return ErrorState(
        errCode:
            appState.data == '' ? 'PRFTP-EMPTY' : 'PRFTP-${appState.data}',
        otherErrorCallbackTitle: 'Retry',
        otherErrorCallback: () async {
          await userStateBloc.handleStateErrors();
        },
      );
    }
  },
);
```

> Acc to docs ,streambuilder gets dispose when we navigate to new screen
> / not in the widget tree

unknowingly i just created a widget instead and pushedReplaced the default screen '/' which then solved this issue,still the issue cause was unknown.

now after some day ,noticed this issue again where a streambuilder which is not a part of tree gets executed when poping the routes.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageController _pgController =
        PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 1);

    final UserStateBloc bloc = UserStateBlocProvider.of(context);
    final DocuwalletBloc docBloc = DocuwalletBlocProvider.of(context);
    final LoginViaOtpBloc loginViaOtpBloc = LoginViaOtpBlocProvider.of(context);
    final UtilsBloc utilsBloc = UtilsBlocProvider.of(context);
    final AnalyticsBloc analyticsBloc = AnalyticsBlocProvider.of(context);
    final BackupBloc backupBloc = BackupBlocProvider.of(context);
    final ScannerBloc scannerBloc = ScannerBlocProvider.of(context);
    return StreamBuilder<UserSessionModel>(
      stream: bloc.userSession,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<UserSessionModel> userSession) {
        if (!userSession.hasData) {
          if (Global.appOpened) {
            return const DefaultLoading();
          }
          return renderUserStateParams(bloc, _pgController, "", "", docBloc,
              utilsBloc, backupBloc, Global.remoteConfigsCache, scannerBloc);
        }
        if (userSession.data!.statusCode != 200) {
          analyticsBloc.logError(AnalyticsConstants.userSession, homeRoute,
              errorData: userSession.data);
          return ErrorState(
            message: userSession.data!.message,
            errCode: 'UCSM-${userSession.data!.statusCode}',
            statusCode: userSession.data!.statusCode,
            otherErrorCallbackTitle: StringConstants.refresh,
            otherErrorCallback: () async {
              await bloc.handleSessionErrors("userHomeScreen", context);
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, authVerificationRoute);
            },
            clientNetworkErrorCallback: () async {
              await bloc.handleSessionErrors("userHomeScreen", context);
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, authVerificationRoute);
            },
            clientNetworkErrorInstructions:
                StringConstants.networkRetryMessage3,
          );
        }
        log(userSession.data!.accessToken);
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: utilsBloc.remoteConfigs,
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<Map<String, String>> configsMap) {
            if (!configsMap.hasData) {
              if (Global.appOpened) {
                return const DefaultLoading();
              } else {
                return renderUserStateParams(
                    bloc,
                    _pgController,
                    userSession.data!.accessToken,
                    userSession.data!.refreshToken,
                    docBloc,
                    utilsBloc,
                    backupBloc,
                    Global.remoteConfigsCache,
                    scannerBloc);
              }
            }
            if (configsMap.hasData && Global.appOpened) {
              bloc.updateFcm(userSession.data!.accessToken,
                  userSession.data!.refreshToken);
              bloc.verifyUserSession(userSession.data!.accessToken,
                  userSession.data!.refreshToken);
              docBloc.deleteRemoteConfigDocTypes(
                configsMap.data![docTypesRemovalKey]!,
              );
              return attachDeviceInfoAndCheckVersion(
                  loginViaOtpBloc,
                  bloc,
                  docBloc,
                  utilsBloc,
                  backupBloc,
                  _pgController,
                  configsMap.data!,
                  userSession.data!.accessToken,
                  userSession.data!.refreshToken,
                  analyticsBloc,
                  scannerBloc);
            }
            return renderUserStateParams(
                bloc,
                _pgController,
                userSession.data!.accessToken,
                userSession.data!.refreshToken,
                docBloc,
                utilsBloc,
                backupBloc,
                configsMap.data!,
                scannerBloc);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  StreamBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>> attachDeviceInfoAndCheckVersion(
      LoginViaOtpBloc loginViaOtpBloc,
      UserStateBloc bloc,
      DocuwalletBloc docBloc,
      UtilsBloc utilsBloc,
      BackupBloc backupBloc,
      PageController pageController,
      Map<String, String> configsMap,
      String accessToken,
      String refreshToken,
      AnalyticsBloc analyticsBloc,
      ScannerBloc scannerBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
      stream: loginViaOtpBloc.deviceInfo,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> deviceInfo) {
        if (!deviceInfo.hasData) {
          return const DefaultLoading();
        }
        if (deviceInfo.data != null &&
            deviceInfo.data!["buildNumber"] != null &&
            configsMap[latestVersionKey] != null &&
            Global.appVersionCheck) {
          int buildNumber = int.tryParse(deviceInfo.data!["buildNumber"]) ?? 0;
          int configBuildNumber =
              int.tryParse(configsMap[latestVersionKey]!) ?? 0;
          //version should always be greater than current version
          if (buildNumber != 0 &&
              configBuildNumber != 0 &&
              configBuildNumber > buildNumber) {
            Future.delayed(
              Duration.zero,
              () => UpdateDialog().showDialog(context, configsMap),
            );
          }
          Global.appVersionCheck = false;
        } else {
          Global.appVersionCheck = false;
        }
        return verifyUserSession(
            bloc,
            docBloc,
            utilsBloc,
            backupBloc,
            pageController,
            accessToken,
            refreshToken,
            analyticsBloc,
            configsMap,
            scannerBloc);
      },
    );
  }

  StreamBuilder<UserVerifySessionModel?> verifyUserSession(
      UserStateBloc bloc,
      DocuwalletBloc docBloc,
      UtilsBloc utilsBloc,
      BackupBloc backupBloc,
      PageController pageController,
      String accessToken,
      String refreshToken,
      AnalyticsBloc analyticsBloc,
      Map<String, String> configsMap,
      ScannerBloc scannerBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder<UserVerifySessionModel?>(
      stream: bloc.verifySession,
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<UserVerifySessionModel?> verifySession) {
        if (verifySession.hasData && verifySession.data!.statusCode != 200) {
          if (verifySession.data!.debugMessage.contains('Token is expired')) {
            bloc.refreshUserSession(refreshToken);
            bloc.addVerifySession(null);
          }
          if (verifySession.data!.debugMessage.contains("User not found")) {
            bloc.handleSessionErrors("userHomeScreenForUserNotFound", context,
                addDelay: true, clearDocs: true);
          }
          return renderUserStateParams(
              bloc,
              pageController,
              accessToken,
              refreshToken,
              docBloc,
              utilsBloc,
              backupBloc,
              configsMap,
              scannerBloc);
          // return ErrorState(
          //     message: verifySession.data!.message,
          //     statusCode: verifySession.data!.statusCode,
          //     errCode: 'UVSM-${verifySession.data!.statusCode}',
          //     otherErrorCallbackTitle: StringConstants.retry,
          //     otherErrorCallback: () {
          //       Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, defaultRoute);
          //     },
          //     clientNetworkErrorCallback: () =>
          //         Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, defaultRoute),
          //     clientNetworkErrorInstructions: StringConstants.retryAgain);
        }
        return renderUserStateParams(
            bloc,
            pageController,
            accessToken,
            refreshToken,
            docBloc,
            utilsBloc,
            backupBloc,
            configsMap,
            scannerBloc);
      },
    );
  }
```

here in this  ,this code gets trigger inside the streambuilder ,which is not a part of current widget tress as i have pushnamed a new route and when i do popUntill ,i can see this method getting triggered.
bloc.handleSessionErrors("userHomeScreenForUserNotFound", context,addDelay: true, clearDocs: true);

weird thing is ,this last issue is observed in release mode not in debug and keyboard issue was obsered in both modes

**UPDATE:**
This is happening when i added the navigation observer ,so whenever pushReplacementUntill is called ,all routes in between trigger their streambuilder builds